# on a specific excell formula

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2013

suppose B2 has a number 10 in it. simultaneously B3,B4,B5,B6 has numbers such as 5,5,8,9 in it. if a number is reduced in cells B3,,B4,B5,B6 the same number gets added in cell B2. For example B3 has a number 5 in it & B2 has a number 10 in it. now the number 5 in B3 is reduced by 1, number 5 in B4 is reduced by 2,number 8 in B5 is reduced by 2 & number 9 in B6 is reduced by 5 then this number 1,2,2,5 gets automatically add to B2, i.e, B2 new number is 10+1+2+2+5=20

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Your post is also very hard to understand. This is why you get downvotes (I assume). I have voted to close this question, but you can [edit your question and improve it](http://superuser.com/posts/1042858/edit). If you do this, I can remove my close vote :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a somewhat hardcoded formula for this so it knows what the number has been reduced by in each cell.

Something like this in cell B2:

```
=10+(5-B3)+(5-B4)+(8-B5)+(9-B6)
```

should achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Jonno has clearly attempted to answer based upon his/her understanding of OP's very difficult to read post

Comment: @Dave Drive-by downvoters :) I appreciate the sentiment - I would edit the question to try and tidy it up, but as I could only edit it to how I *think* the OP wants the question phrased I don't want to risk modifying their intentions. I definitely agree it could be worded in a more understandable way and I could be completely off the mark :)